# Show a tooltip with icon and header in Winforms Listview (only if text is trimmed)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, tooltip

I need to show a tooltip with an icon, a header and a text when the mouse hovers a ListViewSubItem. But the **tooltip** shall **only pop up when** the underlying text of the cell is **trimmed with ellipses**.

Up to now I have the following code:

```
private void ListView_ItemMouseHover(object sender, ListViewItemMouseHoverEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item != null)
    {
        // get last subItem
        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem mySubItem = e.Item.SubItems[item.SubItems.Count - 1];

        // TODO -> how to check if text is trimmmed?
        // e.g. "This is the displayed text in the subitem whi..."

        //if (mySubItem.IsTrimmed???)
        {
            // mToolTip is an instance of ToolTip class
            mToolTip.ToolTipIcon = // any icon...
            mToolTip.ToolTipTitle = "some title text";
            mToolTip.SetToolTip(ListView, "some body text");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mToolTip.Hide(ListView);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this yet?  Seems like it's a good starting point.

Comment: yes kevin, I tried that. But the problem is that I could not figure out how to check whether the displayed text is trimmed or not. Hence, the tooltip is shown in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First measure the size of the drawn string:

```
float realWidth;
using (Graphics g = listView.CreateGraphics()) {
    realWidth= g.MeasureString(mySubItem.Text, mySubItem.Font).Width;
}
```

And find out if its bigger than the current size:

```
if (mySubItem.Bounds.Width > realWidth) {
    // Show tool tip...
}
```

Comment: It turns out that there is no builtin feature/flag to check whether the text in the listview subItem is displayed trimmed or not. Therefore this answer is the best solution for this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For making a custom tooltip box, I think you will have to abandon `ToolTip`. Instead create a `Panel` with the layout you want, then change the `Location` of the `Panel` when you need to display it. You can also add some kind of animation to 'swipe' the `Panel` into view or something. Loading the information you want in the `Panel` to display then displaying.

As for detecting the text that is in the `ListViewItem`, there is an `ItemMouseHover` event that may do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Colin. I already use System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip for displaying a tooltip with an icon, header and body text. 
The remaining issue is that I need to display it conditionally based on whether the underlying text is trimmed.
But SubItem.Text returns the full text.

Comment: @GökhanAkca Do you mean the tooltip automatically trims your text and appends the three ellipses?

Comment: What do you mean 'trimmed'. If you are having no problem displaying your `ToolTip` the way that you want, then you will have to give more details on what it is that you are trying to detect in the `SubItem`. Example is what kind of texts may appear in these `SubItem`s